# MVVM, Navigation, and More

Tags: c#, xaml

Continuation of [Correct MVVM format](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75455/correct-mvvm-format).  This is what I have done so far, and of course it works:

To start with, this is my MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" x:Name="TitleRow"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="DataRow"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" x:Name="ItemsColumn"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="DataColumn"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Background="WhiteSmoke" Name="Items" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemTitles}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
             Margin="-2,-2,0,-2" Padding="0,10" />

    <Viewbox Name="TitleView" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Name="TitleText" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,10,5,5"
                   Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=Items}" />
    </Viewbox>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1"/>

    <Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Margin="20,20,0,20" Name="DataFrame" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

This is the code-behind - MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ViewModel Data = new ViewModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = Data;

        Items.SelectedItem = "Menu 1";
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Data.SelectionChanged(Items.SelectedValue.ToString());
        DataFrame.Navigate(Data.ItemList[Items.SelectedIndex].Page);
    }
}
```

Here is ViewModel.cs:

```cs
public partial class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        GlobalVars.InitMenus();

        ItemList.Add(GlobalVars.Menu1.Menus[0]);
        ItemList.Add(GlobalVars.Menu2.Menus[0]);
        ItemList.Add(GlobalVars.Menu3.Menus[0]);
        ItemList.Add(GlobalVars.Menu4.Menus[0]);

        foreach (MenuItem m in ItemList) ItemTitles.Add(m.Title);
    }

    public void SelectionChanged(string newSelection)
    {
        if (!newSelection.StartsWith(" "))
        {
            ItemList.RemoveAll(x => x.Title.StartsWith(" "));
            ItemTitles.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith(" "));
        }

        switch (newSelection)
        {
            case "Menu 1":

                foreach(MenuItem m in GlobalVars.Menu1.Menus)
                {
                    if (!m.Title.StartsWith(" ")) continue;
                    ItemList.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 1") + 1, m);
                    ItemTitles.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 1") + 1, m.Title);
                }
                break;

            case "Menu 2":

                foreach(MenuItem m in GlobalVars.Menu2.Menus)
                {
                    if (!m.Title.StartsWith(" ")) { continue; }
                    ItemList.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 2") + 1, m);
                    ItemTitles.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 2") + 1, m.Title);
                }
                break;

            case "Menu 3":

                foreach(MenuItem m in GlobalVars.Menu3.Menus)
                {
                    if (!m.Title.StartsWith(" ")) { continue; }
                    ItemList.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 3") + 1, m);
                    ItemTitles.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 3") + 1, m.Title);
                }
                break;

            case "Menu 4":

                foreach(MenuItem m in GlobalVars.Menu4.Menus)
                {
                    if (!m.Title.StartsWith(" ")) { continue; }
                    ItemList.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 4") + 1, m);
                    ItemTitles.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 4") + 1, m.Title);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And VMProperties.cs (a continuation of ViewModel.cs):

```cs
public partial class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _itemList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ItemList
    {
        get { return _itemList; }
        set { _itemList = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _itemTitles = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> ItemTitles
    {
        get { return _itemTitles; }
        set
        {
            if (_itemTitles == value) return;
            _itemTitles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is Menus.cs:

```cs
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(string Title, Type Page)
    {
        _title = Title;
        _page = Page;
    }

    private string _title = "";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { Title = value; }
    }

    private Type _page = null;
    public Type Page
    {
        get { return _page; }
        set { _page = value; }
    }
}

public class Menu
{
    public Menu() { }

    public void Add(MenuItem m)
    {
        Menus.Add(m);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _menus = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Menus
    {
        get { return _menus; }
        set { _menus = value; }
    }
}
```

And this is GlobalVars.cs:

```cs
class GlobalVars
{
    public static void InitMenus()
    {
        var resourceFile = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();

        Menu1.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 1"), typeof(Menus.Menu1)));
        Menu1.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 2"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu2)));
        Menu1.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 1"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu1)));

        Menu2.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 2"), typeof(Menus.Menu2)));
        Menu2.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 4"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu4)));
        Menu2.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 3"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu3)));

        Menu3.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 3"), typeof(Menus.Menu3)));
        Menu3.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 5"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu5)));

        Menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 4"), typeof(Menus.Menu4)));
        Menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 10"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu10)));
        Menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 9"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu9)));
        Menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 8"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu8)));
        Menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 7"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu7)));
        Menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 6"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu6)));
    }

    private static Menu _menu1 = new Menu();
    public static Menu Menu1
    {
        get { return _menu1; }
    }

    private static Menu _menu2 = new Menu();
    public static Menu Menu2
    {
        get { return _menu2; }
    }

    private static Menu _menu3 = new Menu();
    public static Menu Menu3
    {
        get { return _menu3; }
    }

    private static Menu _menu4 = new Menu();
    public static Menu Menu4
    {
        get { return _menu4; }
    }
}
```

[Extension.cs](http://pastebin.com/NJ82tjdW) contains the code for `ObservableCollection.RemoveAll()`, taken from SO.

These are the values in Resources.resw:

```cs
Menu 1         Menu 1
Menu 10        Menu 10
Menu 11        Menu 11
Menu 12        Menu 12
Menu 13        Menu 13
Menu 14        Menu 14
Menu 2         Menu 2
Menu 3         Menu 3
Menu 4         Menu 4
Menu 5         Menu 5
Menu 6         Menu 6
Menu 7         Menu 7
Menu 8         Menu 8
Menu 9         Menu 9
Submenu 1      Submenu 1
Submenu 10     Submenu 10
Submenu 2      Submenu 2
Submenu 3      Submenu 3
Submenu 4      Submenu 4
Submenu 5      Submenu 5
Submenu 6      Submenu 6
Submenu 7      Submenu 7
Submenu 8      Submenu 8
Submenu 9      Submenu 9
```

I would like my navigation, use of MVVM, and everything else reviewed.  I hate the way I have to have `ItemsTitle` separate from `ItemList`, but my ListBox would not update in response to my clicks any other way.  I am not at all sure I am doing this right, and that is why I want it reviewed.  I do want to keep one `ObservableCollection` or some other collection type per menu so I don't have to iterate over hundreds of values each time I need to insert a new list.  I know I can't have menus inside menus, but I don't want that feature now anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

1. You should have a property on your `ViewModel` which represents the `SelectedItem` as well as the `SelectedPage`. In your `MainPage` you would bind then the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` to the view model property and the `Source` of the `Frame` to the `SelectedPage` property. This way when someone selects a new item you can handle the change entirely inside the view model and getting rid of the code-behind in your `MainPage`. The advantage is that you can easily unit test the behaviour of menu selection.
2. Your handling code for the different menus inside the `ViewModel` is repeating code at it's best. This code block:

   > ```
   >         foreach(MenuItem m in GlobalVars.Menu1.Menus)
   >         {
   >             if (!m.Title.StartsWith(" ")) continue;
   >             ItemList.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 1") + 1, m);
   >             ItemTitles.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf("Menu 1") + 1, m.Title);
   >         }
   > ```

   can be generalized into a method:

   ```
   private void HandleMenuSelection(string menu, IList<MenuItem> menuItems)
   {
       foreach (var m in menuItems)
       {
           if (!m.Title.StartsWith(" ")) continue;
           ItemList.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf(menu) + 1, m);
           ItemTitles.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf(menu) + 1, m.Title);  
       }          
   }
   ```

   in which case your switch would start reading like:

   ```
   switch (newSelection)
   {
       case "Menu 1": HandleMenuSelection(newSelection, GlobalVars.Menu1.Menus); break;
       case "Menu 2": HandleMenuSelection(newSelection, GlobalVars.Menu2.Menus); break;
       ...
   }
   ```
3. I strongly dislike the `GlobalVars` class. There is an implicit dependency from the view model to it via the `Menu 1`, `Menu 2`, etc. magic strings which is not easily visible and makes the code brittle. It would be better to create an interfacelike an `IMenuSource` which can be queried for the different menus. This will make unit testing the code easier as well.

---

**Update** To clarify on point 3 above.

I would consider creating an interface which provides the required information about the available menus. Something along these lines:

```
public interface IMenuProvider
{
    IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetMainMenus();
    IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetSubMenus(string menuName);
}
```

which you can then implement accordingly and inject into your `ViewModel` which would then look more like this:

```
public partial class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IMenuProvider _MenuProvider;

    public ViewModel(IMenuProvider menuProvider)
    {
        ItemList.AddRange(menuProvider.GetMainMenus());

        foreach (MenuItem m in ItemList) ItemTitles.Add(m.Title);
    }

    public void SelectionChanged(string newSelection)
    {
        if (!newSelection.StartsWith(" "))
        {
            ItemList.RemoveAll(x => x.Title.StartsWith(" "));
            ItemTitles.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith(" "));
        }

        foreach (var m in menuProvider.GetSubMenus(newSelection))
        {
            if (!m.Title.StartsWith(" ")) continue;
            ItemList.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf(newSelection) + 1, m);
            ItemTitles.Insert(ItemTitles.IndexOf(newSelection) + 1, m.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

It has also the advantage that the application code doesn't have to know what menus exist so they could easily come from a database or other configuration file. When adding a new menu no code has to change.

Example implementation could be:

```
public class ResourceMenuProvider : IMenuProvider
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Menu> _Menus = new Dictionary<string, Menu>();

    static ResourceMenuProvider()
    {
        var resourceFile = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();

        var menu1 = new Menu();
        menu1.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 1"), typeof(Menus.Menu1)));
        menu1.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 2"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu2)));
        menu1.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 1"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu1)));
        _Menus["Menu 1"] = menu1;

        var menu2 = new Menu();
        menu2.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 2"), typeof(Menus.Menu2)));
        menu2.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 4"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu4)));
        menu2.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 3"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu3)));
        _Menus["Menu 2"] = menu2;

        var menu3 = new Menu();
        menu3.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 3"), typeof(Menus.Menu3)));
        menu3.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 5"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu5)));
        _Menus["Menu 3"] = menu3;

        var menu4 = new Menu();
        menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Menu 4"), typeof(Menus.Menu4)));
        menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 10"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu10)));
        menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 9"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu9)));
        menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 8"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu8)));
        menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 7"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu7)));
        menu4.Add(new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("Submenu 6"), typeof(Menus.MenuItems.Submenu6)));
        _Menus["Menu 4"] = menu4;
    }

    IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetMainMenus()
    {
        return _Menus.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Menus.First());
    }

    IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetSubMenus(string menuName)
    {
        return _Menus[menuName].Menus.Skip(1); // skip main menu
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hosch250: Well, I'd re-implement `GlobalVars` as a `ResourceMenuProvider` - see added example implementation.